# html-react-parser will not parse onChange function on select tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am attempting to dynamically create multiple select drop downs in a loop. The html-react-parser works fine when there is just pure html in it. However, when I add a onChange function to the select tag, it does not parse that part correctly. It actually seems to just disregard it.

```
 let selectOptions = "<th>Details</th>";
 for(var j=0;j<envsToCommitsHolder.length;j++){
        selectOptions += "<th><select onChange={(event) => {handleOptionSelection(event.target.selectedOptions)}} id="+realRepoName[j+1]+"><option>"+realRepoName[j+1]+"</option>";       
        for(var h=0;h<envsToCommitsHolder[j].val.length;h++){
          console.log(realRepoName[j+1]);
          console.log(envsToCommitsHolder[j].val[h]);    
          //var value = envsToCommitsHolder[j].val[h];      
          selectOptions += "<option value="+h+">"+envsToCommitsHolder[j].val[h]+"</option>";          
        }
        selectOptions += "</select></th>";      
      }     
      return parse(selectOptions);
```

Please see the attached image to see how it is being rendered. It puts the javascript outside of the select tag altogether. Is there some other way I should be doing this? I have attached the image of how the select with the onChange is being rendered on the browser ->
[problematic part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eX0h.png). I also saw there is a "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" to parse string and render html out of it, but I am not sure how to use that or if it will be useful in this case or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am quite stuck with this one.

Comment: `onChange={(event) => {handleOptionSelection(event.target.selectedOptions)}}` this string will not work in pure HTML, ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp. it only can be used with react

Comment: I am using react. Also, changing it to something like onchange="test()" does not work either. It completely just ignores that whole part.

Comment: yeah, when using React, I recommend should NOT make some changes to the DOM directly (not through React), it is not good to handle events relevant

Comment: @H294 How do you suggest I do this then? problem is, the data is coming in from API calls. So I have to create the select boxes dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sandbox to render the select options dynamically, you can custom the rendering on your own, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-8psy13?file=/src/App.tsx
Basic React knowledge: useState, useEffect
If y have a question, you can ask me here